# How to test Database implementation for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing

I wrote my Database Layer and my CRUD Methods for my Android Application.

Now i am wondering how to test my layer?

I wrote a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CRUD crud = new CRUD();
    Location location = new Location(1.0,null, "TestData1");
    CRUD.insertLocation(location);
    System.out.println("Location successfully added!" + location.locationToString());
    crud.removeLocation(location);
    System.out.println("Location successfully deleted!" + location.locationToString());
}
```

But when I am doing Debug as> Web Application the compiler says these Exceptions:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

So how to test if the DataLayer is right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Local Unit Testing for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.) from the App Engine documentation (FYI it is the first result on Google for "app engine java unit test").